# Fastest way to cast 4 bytes to Float32 in Julia?

Tags: optimization, vector, casting, io, julia

I have a `mmap`ed array of `Vector{UInt8}` and i'd like to cast 4 bytes from a specific position to `Float32`. Currently I can do this by

```
f1(a, i) = reinterpret(Float32, x[i:i+3])[]
f2(a, i) = read(IOBuffer(x[i:i+3]), Float32)
```

Both return the desired result. However, it seems the compiler does not optimize out the `Array` or `IOBuffer` construction (@code_native gives dozens of lines). How can I cast them like in C `(*float) (p + i)`?

Comment: Does this work for you: 'f(a, i) = unsafe_load(Ptr{Float32}(pointer(a, i)))'? EDIT: byte order will be important here to get a proper result.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński That's perfect! Thanks!