# Parse array of unsigned integers in Julia 1.x.x

Tags: parsing, julia, binaryfiles

I am trying to open a binary file that I have some knowledge of its internal structure, and reinterpret it correctly in Julia. Let us say that I can load it already via:

```
arx=open("../axonbinaryfile.abf", "r")  
databin=read(arx)  
close(arx)
```

The data is loaded as an Array of UInt8, which I guess are bytes.
In the first 4 I can perform a simple `Char` conversion and it works:

```
head=databin[1:4]
map(Char, head)

4-element Array{Char,1}:
 'A'
 'B'
 'F'
 ' '
```

Then it happens to be that in the positions 13-16 is an integer of 32 bytes waiting to be interpreted. How should I do that?
I have tried `reinterpret()` and `Int32` as function, but to no avail.

Comment: [possibly duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49973143/fastest-way-to-cast-4-bytes-to-float32-in-julia)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `reinterpret(Int32, databin[13:16])[1]`.  The last `[1]` is needed, because `reinterpret` returns you a view.

Now note that `read` supports type passing. So if you first read 12 bytes of data from your file e.g. like this `read(arx, 12)` and then run `read(arx, Int32)` you will get the desired number without having to do any conversions or vector allocation.

Finally observe that what conversion to `Char` does in your code is converting a Unicode number to a character. I am not sure if this is exactly what you want (maybe it is). For example if the first byte read in has value `200` you will get:

```
julia> Char(200)
'È': Unicode U+00c8 (category Lu: Letter, uppercase)
```

**EDIT** one more comment is that when you do a conversion to `Int32` of 4 bytes you should be sure to check if it should be encoded as big-endian or little-endian (see `ENDIAN_BOM` constant and `ntoh`, `hton`, `ltoh`, `htol` functions)

Comment: It seems that `read` is doing the work fine. Now I have another problem with that. It cannot read an array of `Int16` even though `isa(Array{Int16,1}`, Type) tells me it is a valid type.

Comment: It will not work because `Vector{Int16}` does not have a defined size. The method `read(io, T)` handles only a limited set of types `T` (it is true that the documentation could be more precise here). You can do two things. Either read `Int16` repeatedly as many times as you need, or read in `Vector{UInt8}` using the other methods recommended and then `reinterpret(Int16, data_read_in)` to get a `Vector{Int16}`.

Comment: This is a special case for a commonly needed thing to get all data as a string from the source.

Answer (score 2):

Here it is. Use `view` to avoid copying the data.

```
julia> dat = UInt8[65,66,67,68,0,0,2,40];

julia> Char.(view(dat,1:4))
4-element Array{Char,1}:
 'A'
 'B'
 'C'
 'D'

julia> reinterpret(Int32, view(dat,5:8))
1-element reinterpret(Int32, view(::Array{UInt8,1}, 5:8)):
 671219712
```